# How to sort by multiple fields using case sensitive

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

As simple sorting by two values in Kotlin can be like this:

`.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.lastName }, { it.firstName }))`

How to sort by those 2 field and adding case insensitive order? 
I know that this can be only applied to sorting by one field:

`.sortedWith(compareBy(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER, { it.lastName })`

How to do this for both fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not like this?

```
.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.lastName.toLowerCase() }, { it.firstName.toLowerCase() }))
```

Comment: Is it possible to also sort with localization? So for example order should be like this "a, ą, c, ć, z, ż"